# How to select an element that depends on another by XPath

Tags: xpath

I need to build an `xpath` that returns `my element` only if `dependency` is present on the screen.

I'm currently filtering `my element` using the following snippet:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'my element')]
```

```html
...
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a>dependency</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <div>my element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//div[contains(text(), 'my element')][//a[contains(text(), 'dependency')]]
```